# wordpress entire site content shifted to right, need to center it again

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im working on a wordpress site that has already been built. 
I'm just editing one page, and adding an accordion menu to it. 
But I possibly have done something wrong today, as most of the site content 
even on other pages has just shifted to the right, even though I did nothing with the other pages.

I have even completely removed the work I was doing to see if this would revert and fix the problem but it didnt work.

at the moment I don't have access to the html files Im just editing on wordpress.

site link [here](https://westportbikes4hire.com/)

Thanks, Andrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be your issue. Remove the float :)

```
.ak-container {
width: 1140px;
margin: 0 auto;
/* float: right; */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you legend! :) I dont know how that .ak-container got "float: right;", because Im not actually editing the html or css files themselves. so in saying that its difficult remove it as I dont have access to the html and css files, but I will try and get access to them. Thank you so much & happy christmas !

Comment: Im trying to think, what could be a better name for this question?